# Are there any performance issues with storing application settings as an App() static variable vs using the properties dictionary?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm currently storing application specific variables like this:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
   public static int id;
```

When my application starts I load these values from a table in a database and when they change I change the value plus update the database.

Here I understand there's a different way to do this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/application-class#Properties_Dictionary

```
if (Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("id"))
{
   var id = Application.Current.Properties["id"] as int;
   // do something with id
}
```

But when I try to code this using the same code as in the Xamarin example page it gives me an error:

```
App.xaml.cs(26,26): Error CS0077: The as operator must be used with a reference type or nullable type ('int' is a non-nullable value type) (CS0077)
```

Can someone tell me how I can fix this error and also is it more efficient to use the properties dictionary vs storing the information in a SQLLite database?

Comment: try using "int id = (int)Application.Current.Properties["id"];"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Properties` dictionary is saved to the device while the `static` variables in your `App` class are not persisted (they exist in memory while your app is running).

So it depends, if you want to persist information across lifecycle state changes, the `Properties` dictionary is your way to go.

Comment: Does the properties dictionary work if the application is later upgraded with a new version do you know?

Comment: Yes, it is maintained across versions